# Reading data from a file in C

Tags: c

I have a data file and I want to read it into a struct.

This is the contents of the data file

```
Japan 46.2 16 12.7
Spain 42.8 18.5 39.3
Italy 53.25 19.8 32.8
France 54.5 21.1 31.4
Turkey 52.5 15.6 19.1
```

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    

    struct covid
    {
        char location[100];
        double does_given;
        double full_vaccinated;
        double of_population_fully_vaccinated;
    };

    FILE *infile;
    infile=fopen("test.txt","r");
    
    if (infile == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError opening file\n");
        exit (1);
    }

    struct covid stats;
    
    while (fread(&stats,sizeof(struct covid),1,infile)){
        printf("name =%s, give =%f, full=%f, pop=%f\n",stats.location, stats.does_given, stats.full_vaccinated, stats.of_population_fully_vaccinated);
        
    };

    fclose(infile);
    return 0;
    
}
```

However, when I run this code, I get no output. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: As for your problem, you try to read raw binary structures from a text file, which will not work. You need to read the file line by line, and then parse each line to get its value to put into structures. Hint: `fgets` and `sscanf` could be useful.

Comment: @Gerhardh  Can i use .dat file?

Comment: @kokiwebaaa what is a .dat file?

Comment: Now COVID managed to infect even programming languages... :-D

Comment: @Jabberwocky A file with the .dat file extension is a generic data file that stores specific information relating to the program that created the file.

Comment: You can name your file whatever you want, it's the actual contents and its format that dictates how you need to read and parse the file. If it's a text file where each line in a single record, it doesn't matter if the file is named `foo.txt`, `foo.dat` or `foo.bar`, you must still read it line by line and parse each line.

Comment: A .dat file can mean anything or nothing. You show that your file contains human readable text. This does not match any struct layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file contains textual representations of numbers, you cannot blindly read that text into a struct, there is no magic that will transform the textual representation  into doubles.

You need to read the file line by line and parse each line individually.

You want something like this:

```
  char line[1000];

  while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), infile)) {
    sscanf(line, "%s %lf %lf %lf", stats.location, &stats.does_given,
                  &stats.full_vaccinated, &stats.of_population_fully_vaccinated);

    printf("name =%s, give =%f, full=%f, pop=%f\n", stats.location, stats.does_given,
            stats.full_vaccinated, stats.of_population_fully_vaccinated);
  };
```

Disclaimer: there is no error checking whatsoever.