# using malloc - c programming

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I'm wondering if anyone can help me with my below code. I'm struggling to implement dynamic allocation for my program when reading data from a file and storing it in a struct. I'm new to both structs and dynamic allocation. While my program seems to be storing the data successfully into the struct I can see in Visual Studio that the allocation of these is not correct. Any advice on storing the data dynamic would be much appreciated. I was trying to use malloc but could not get this to work for me.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void load_data();


typedef struct {
    char name[12];
    char vaccinevendor[8];
    char vaccinationdate[12];
    char dob[12];
    char underlyingcond[8];
    char id[7];
}  Record;



int main(void)
{

    load_data();

    return 0;
}

void load_data()
{
    
    Record s1[2];


    FILE* Ptr;  /*file pointer*/

    if ((Ptr = fopen("records.txt", "rb")) == NULL) {
        printf("File does not exist\n");
    
        Ptr = fopen("records.txt", "w");
        if (Ptr != NULL)
            printf("records.txt file has now been created.\n");
        else {
            printf("Unable to create file!\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }


     Ptr = (char*)malloc(1000 * sizeof(char));

    // read file contents till end of file
    fread(&s1, sizeof(Record), 2, Ptr);
    
    fclose(Ptr); /*close stream*/

}
```

Hi all,

As per my comment below I have updated my code but am getting errors when trying to store my array strings into my struct. As I was asked in the comments also, the test file contents are lines in the following format:

```
John Smith
Pfizer
02/08/2021
06/01/1990
None
556679

Mary Jones
None
None
09/10/1988
Asthma
556677
```

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 13
#define stringlen 15
#define numoflines 12

void load_data();


typedef struct {
    char name[12];
    char vaccinevendor[8];
    char vaccinationdate[12];
    char dob[12];
    char underlyingcond[8];
    char id[7];
}  Record;



int main(void)
{

    load_data();

    return 0;
}

void load_data()
{
    char line[110], buff[13][50];
    int len;
    int i = 0;

    Record s1[2];


    FILE* Ptr;  /*file pointer*/

    if ((Ptr = fopen("records.txt", "rb")) == NULL) {
        printf("File does not exist\n");
    
        Ptr = fopen("records.txt", "w");
        if (Ptr != NULL)
            printf("records.txt file has now been created.\n");
        else {
            printf("Unable to create file!\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
    {
        len = strlen(buff[i]);
        fgets(buff[i], 21, Ptr);
        s1[0] = malloc(len);
        strcpy(s1[i], buff);
    }

    fclose(Ptr); /*close stream*/

}
```

Comment: As an aside, your `void` function should not `return` a return value...

Comment: `Ptr = (char*)malloc(1000 * sizeof(char));` . `Ptr` is not of type `char *`. You should create a new varaible for this. You also can't close a char pointer.

Comment: Please [edit] and show the first 5-6 lines of record.txt. As it's name suggsts, it's a text file, therefore `fread` is wrong. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70663632/reading-data-from-a-file-in-c/) deals with that problem.

Comment: Also it's very unclear what you're trying to do. Please [edit] and show the requirements.

Comment: "Any advice on ..." --> Yes.  Enable all warnings.  Then your compiler will give you quicker feedback than posting on SO.  Example "warning: 'return' with a value, in function returning void [-Wreturn-type]", `return 1;` "warning: assignment to 'FILE *' from incompatible pointer type 'char *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]" `Ptr = (char*) malloc(1000 * sizeof(char));`

Comment: Hi everyone, I changed my code to the below. I think it's a better way of reading in the info from the file and storing in my struct. I'm getting a message though when using malloc that "type void cannot be assigned to an entity of type record". What I'm trying to do though is store this in the string (now stored in buff) into the char variables in struct. Any ideas of what i'm missing?

Comment: @CiaranKiernan your new code does not compile, is that what you mean by _"but am getting errors when trying to store my array strings into my struct"_?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yeah my code does not compile. I'm just not sure what to change on that. I am getting errors for the line containing the malloc and strcpy functions. I have now included these above. I have only started to learn about structs and dynamic memory allocation so am unsure exactly of how to go about getting the above working.

Comment: The problem is your code makes no sense whatsoever. What _exactly_ is your program supposed to do?

Comment: @CiaranKiernan and don't mess up my edits.

Comment: @Jabberwocky The program will be larger than you see above, but the load_data() function needs to take in the text as I've pasted above and store them in the corresponding Record variables. It needs to also allocate memory dynamically. The test strings are in the same order as the Record struct variables (name, vaccinevendor, vaccinationdate, dob, underlyingcond, id). I was attempting to save the strings to the buff array and then copy them to the s1 srtuct Record array.

Answer (score 1):

Correcting the obvious error

```
// Ptr = (char*)malloc(1000 * sizeof(char));

// read file contents till end of file
fread(&s1, sizeof(Record), 2, Ptr);

fclose(Ptr); /*close stream*/
```

the commented out line is clearly thinking it neeeds to 'allocate a buffer' in some way. No, s1 is the buffer, and you certainly never want to change Ptr (its the pointer to the internals of the file system).

However this code almost certainly wont work unless your file is very precisely laid out. For example it needs to start like this (in hex)

```
4141414100000000000000004242420000000000
```

if the fist name is "AAAA" and the first vendor is "BBB". And even then it might not work due to struct padding issues

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not really make sense. `Ptr` points to the file opened through `fopen` which is fine. But then you allocate dynamic memory (through `malloc`) and assign the adress of this memory to the same `Ptr`. So basically you have lost the previous value of `Ptr`, in other terms the reference to your file (not to mention `Ptr` is of type `FILE *` and you assign to it a `char *`).

You don't need to allocate memory for `Ptr`, you need to allocate memory for the buffer where you copy data from this file. But here `s1` is located on the stack, you don't need dynamic memory allocation.

Also be careful when copying raw data to a `struct`. Data structures may have "holes" in between their fields depending on data alignement (here as you have only `char`arrays, all the fields are probably contiguous).

I suggest you learn about data structures and the different kinds of memory allocation in C.